# Keep getting 401 error when I create playlist using spotify api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spotify

I am trying to create a playlist using the spotify api but I keep getting 401 errors, my token works for searching and getting audio features but not for creating playlists.

Here is how I get my auth token

```
  const REDIRECT_URI="http://localhost:3000/"
    const AUTH_ENDPOINT="https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize"
    const RESPONSE_TYPE = "token"
    const SCOPES="playlist-modify-private playlist-modify-public user-read-private"

 useEffect(()=>{
        const hash=window.location.hash
        let token =window.localStorage.getItem("token")
        setToken(token)

        
        if(hash){
            let temp=hash;

            temp= temp.split('&');

            temp=temp[0];
            temp=temp.split("=")

            temp=temp[1];
            window.location.hash=""
            window.localStorage.setItem("token",temp)
            setToken(temp)
        }

        
       
    },[])

 {!token ?
            <div>
                {/* &scope=${SCOPES} */}
                <h1 className="title"> Spotify Stats</h1>
                <a className="logIn" href={`${AUTH_ENDPOINT}?client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}&response_type=${RESPONSE_TYPE}&scope=${SCOPES}`}>Logg in</a>
            </div>
            :
```

and here is my function to make a playlist

```
 async function makePlaylist(){
        console.log(props.token)
        console.log("make Play")
        setPlaylistName("")
        const myId= await getMe()
        console.log(myId)


        const urlPlay="https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/"+myId+"/playlists"
        props.changePlaylist([])
 
        await axios.post(urlPlay,{
            headers:{
                Authorization:`Bearer ${props.token}`
            },
            body:
                JSON.stringify({name: "New Playliddddst",
                description: "New playlist description",
                public: false})
              
        })
        
     }
```

I know my getMe() function to get the user's id works because when I make the request it shows the user id in the link that has been attempted to be posted.

Also I tried using the token from Spotify web api console because I was able to create a playlist there using a specific token, however when I used that token on makePlaylist() I still got the 401 error despite that token working for other spotify api features such as searching.

Comment: did you try to debug your api request with something like Postman?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you already figured this out but for others that come across this (like myself, as I just had this issue).

You need to add the body of the axios request first. Specifically, the name tag is the only required field. So yours should look something like this:

```
await axios.post(urlPlay, {
        name: "New Playliddddst",
        description: "New playlist description",
        public: false,
    },
    {
        headers:{
            Authorization:`Bearer ${props.token}`
        },
    }, 
})
```